# PowerShell: How to install a PFX certificate on a remote computer in 'CurrentUser' store location?

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have tried Import-PfxCertificate with Invoke-Command but I think it requires the certificate file to be copied first on remote server. And i also think it requires the credentials to be delegated.

As per the below link the .Net classes does not support 'CurrentUser' -

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/16/use-powershell-and-net-to-find-expired-certificates.aspx

"Of these two certificate store locations, only LocalMachine can be accessed remotely via the .NET class. Attempting to access CurrentUser will result in an “Access Denied” message because of security reasons."

Is there any way to accomplish this using PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a PSSession to step into the remote PC.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName RemoteSystem
   #...Prompt changes and commands are now executing on the remote sysem
   #change the store location to the appropriate store you'd like to put the CERT
   Import-PFXCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher -FilePath \\server\path\to\cert.pfx
 Exit-PSSession
```

this would be the simplest way to do it, and any other command which must execute on a locate system.

If you need to do this in a script across a large number of systems:

```
$computers = #get a bunch of computers, either a txt file, csv or whatever
ForEach ($remoteSystem in $computers){

    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteSystem
       #Commands below this point will execute remotely
       Import-PFXCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher -FilePath \\server\path\to\cert.pfx
    Exit-PSSession
}
```

Done!

Comment: Thanks for the response but getting this error.  "Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). This may be the result of user credentials being required on the remote machine. See Enable-WSManCredSSP Cmdlet help on how to enable and use CredSSP for delegation with PowerShell remoting."

Comment: Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -FilePath \\172.xx.xx.xx\Shared\Certs\pravesh.com.pfx . Executed this command after Enter-PSSession . .

Comment: Get PowerShell remoting working first. Run Get-help about_remoting for an excellent guide on the topic.

Comment: What about a pfx that requires a password?

Answer (score 0):

I had a double hop authentication problem with above solution. Below code worked well for me. Hope it helps! :)

```
        [byte[]]$Pfxinbyts = Get-Content "$FullPathWithFileName.pfx" -Encoding byte
        Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    param(
        [byte[]] $PFXCertInByte,
        [string] $CertRootStore,
        [string] $CertStore,
        [string] $X509Flags,
        $PfxPass)
    $Pfx = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
    $Pfx.Import([byte[]]$PFXCertInByte, $PfxPass, $X509Flags)
    $Store = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -ArgumentList $CertStore, $CertRootStore
    $Store.Open("MaxAllowed")
    $Store.Add($Pfx)
    if ($?)
    {
        "${Env:ComputerName}: Successfully added certificate."
    }
    else
    {
        "${Env:ComputerName}: Failed to add certificate! $($Error[0].ToString() -replace '[\r\n]+', ' ')"
    }
    $Store.Close()
} -ArgumentList $Pfxinbyts, "LocalMachine", "My", "Exportable,PersistKeySet", $PFXPassword
```